# mysql update + ( where + join) syntax

Tags: mysql, join, where-clause

```
    $rs = mysql_query("
        SELECT a.id 
        FROM a
        JOIN b ON b.id=a.id
        WHERE 
            b.p1=1 AND 
            a.p1=1");

    while($r = mysql_fetch_assoc($rs))
        $ids[] = $r['id'];

    $rs = mysql_query("
        UPDATE a
        SET p2=2 
        WHERE id IN (".implode(",",$ids).")");
```

How to do this in one query?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
UPDATE a
JOIN   b ON a.id=b.id AND a.p1 = 1 AND b.p1 = 1
SET    a.p2 = 2
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using `INNER JOIN` which performs better than `IN` clause:

```
UPDATE a
       INNER JOIN b
           ON b.id=a.id
              AND b.p1 = 1
              AND a.p1 = 1
SET p2 = 2;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE a
SET p2=2 
WHERE id IN (SELECT a.id 
        FROM a
        JOIN b ON b.id=a.id
        WHERE 
            b.p1=1 AND 
            a.p1=1)
```

Comment: you can not update table where the same table used in the sub query `from`